# Can access firebase admin through firebase funcition

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
 const userId = context.params.user_id
 const notificationId = context.params.notification_id
 console.log(userId) 

 if(!change.after.val()){
    return console.log('A notification has been deleted in database: ', notificationId);
 }

 return admin.database.ref('/Users/'+userId).once('value')
 .then(function(snapshot){
   const token_id = snapshot.child('device_token').val()
   console.log(token_id)

 })

});
```

I tried to get device token which stored in firebase realtime database using firebase function and firebase admin

[image]

This is my database
[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't share pictures of text.  What you have now is very difficult to read.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `admin.database.ref(...)` you will need `admin.database().ref(...)`.  Note the parenthesis after "database" - it's a method call.